# sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter, windows10, sqlite3

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño programa para inserción de info para creación de bases de datos, pero al momento de querer crear un nuevo registro me aparece el siguiente error a partir de la línea 72:

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

el error completo indica:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\MaJii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1885, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\MaJii\OneDrive\Escritorio\Tesis
> PC\Python\Práctica_guiada\pyum.py", line 72, in crear
> miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATOS_FARMACOS VALUES (NULL, '" + miNombre.get() +

La línea 72 es la siguiente:

`miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATOS_FARMACOS VALUES(NULL, '" + miNombre.get() +`

El resto del código es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
#---------------------------------------------------------Funcionalidades---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#---------------------------------------------------------Menú base de datos
# Creación de base de datos

def conexionBBDD():

    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("Registro de Fármacos")

    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

    try:

        miCursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE DATOS_FARMACOS (
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
            NOMBRE_FÁRMACO VARCHAR (50),
            CLASIFICACIÓN_FARMACOLÓGICA VARCHAR (50),
            USO_HUMANO VARCHAR (100),
            USO_ANIMAL VARCHAR (100),
            FUNCIONES VARCHAR (150),
            INTERACCIONES_FF VARCHAR (200),
            INTERACCIONES_FE VARCHAR (200),
            PROPORCIONES_USO VARCHAR (250))
            ''')

        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Base de datos creada con éxito")

    except: 

        messagebox.showwarning("Intento fallido", "La base de datos ya ha sido creada")


# Salir de la aplicación 

def salirAplicacion():

    pregunta = messagebox.askquestion("Salir", "¿Deseas salir de la aplicación?")

    if pregunta == "yes":
        root.destroy()

#---------------------------------------------------------Menú borrar
#Borrar campos

def borrarCampos():

    miID.set("")
    miNombre.set("")
    miClas.set("")
    miHum.set("")
    miAnim.set("")
    cuadroFun.delete(1.0, END) #para indicar qué caracteres borrar
    miFF.set("")
    miFE.set("")
    cuadroProp.delete(1.0, END)

#-----------------------------------------------------Menú CRUD

def crear():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("Registro de Fármacos")

    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATOS_FARMACOS VALUES(NULL, '" + miNombre.get() +
        "','" + miClas.get() +
        "','" + miHum.get() +
        "','" + miAnim.get() +
        "','" + cuadroFun.get("1.0", END) +
        "','" + miFF.get() +
        "','" + miFE.get() +
        "','" + cuadroProp.get("1.0", END) + "')")

    miConexion.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro realizado exitosamente")

#----------------------------------------------- Personalización de ventana----------------------------------------------------#
root = Tk()
root.title("Inserción de datos sobre fármacos")
root.iconbitmap("mortero.ico")
root.config(bg = "black", bd = 15, relief = "sunken", cursor = "hand2")

#------------------------------------------------ Menú de opciones-------------------------------------------------------------#
barraMenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = barraMenu, width = 300, height = 300)

#-------Menú de bases de datos
bbddMenu = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
bbddMenu.add_command(label = "Conectar", command = conexionBBDD)
bbddMenu.add_command(label = "Salir", command = salirAplicacion)

#-----Menú borrar
borrarMenu = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
borrarMenu.add_command(label = "Borrar campos", command = borrarCampos)

#-----Menú CRUD
crudMenu = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
crudMenu.add_command(label = "Crear", command = crear)
crudMenu.add_command(label = "Leer")
crudMenu.add_command(label = "Actualizar")
crudMenu.add_command(label = "Borrar")

#-----Menú ayuda
helpMenu = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
helpMenu.add_command(label = "Licencia")
helpMenu.add_command(label = "Acerca de...")
helpMenu.add_command(label = "Contacto")

#----Opciones desplegables de menú
barraMenu.add_cascade(label = "BBDD", menu = bbddMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label = "Borrar", menu = borrarMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label = "CRUD", menu = crudMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label = "Ayuda", menu = helpMenu)

#----------------------------------------------------------Creación del primer Frame -----------------------------------------------#

miFrame = Frame(root)
miFrame.pack()

#Para poder modificar los datos de nuestras bases de datos, asignamos a cada entry una función de variable tipo string: 
miID = StringVar()
miNombre = StringVar()
miClas = StringVar()
miHum = StringVar()
miAnim = StringVar()
#miFun
miFF = StringVar()
miFE = StringVar()
#miProp


#A las funciones que se consideren texto no es necesario asignar estas variables

cuadroID = Entry(miFrame, textvariable = miID) #verificar más tarde por si son numéricos
cuadroID.grid(row = 8, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10) 

cuadroNombre = Entry (miFrame, textvariable = miNombre)
cuadroNombre.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
cuadroNombre.config(fg = "red", justify = "center")

cuadroClas = Entry(miFrame, textvariable = miClas)
cuadroClas.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroHum = Entry(miFrame, textvariable =  miHum)
cuadroHum.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroAnim = Entry(miFrame, textvariable = miAnim)
cuadroAnim.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroFun = Text(miFrame, width = 15, height = 8)
cuadroFun.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroFF = Entry(miFrame, textvariable = miFF)
cuadroFF.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroFE = Entry(miFrame, textvariable = miFE)
cuadroFE.grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

cuadroProp = Text(miFrame, width = 15, height = 8)
cuadroProp.grid(row = 7, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

#---------------scrolls
#Funciones

scrollFun = Scrollbar(miFrame, command = cuadroFun.yview)
scrollFun.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

cuadroFun.config(yscrollcommand = scrollFun)

#Proporciones

scrollProp = Scrollbar(miFrame, command = cuadroFun.yview)
scrollProp.grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

cuadroProp.config(yscrollcommand = scrollProp)


#-----------------------------------------------------------Creación de Labels-------------------------------------------------------#
IDLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "ID de producto: ")
IDLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

NombreLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Nombre de fármaco:")
NombreLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

ClasLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Clasificación farmacológica:")
ClasLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

HumLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Uso en humanos:")
HumLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

AnimLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Uso en animales:")
AnimLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

FunLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Funciones:")
FunLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

FFLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Interacciones fármaco-fármaco:")
FFLabel.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

FELabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Interacciones fármaco-excipiente:")
FELabel.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

PropLabel = Label(miFrame, text = "Proporciones de uso:")
PropLabel.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)


#----------------------------------------------------------Botones (Frame 2)----------------------------------------------------------#
miFrame2 = Frame (root)
miFrame2.pack()

botonC = Button(miFrame2, text = "Crear", command = crear)
botonC.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

botonR = Button(miFrame2, text = "Leer")
botonR.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

botonU = Button(miFrame2, text = "Actualizar")
botonU.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)

botonD = Button(miFrame2, text = "Borrar")
botonD.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = "e", padx = 10, pady = 10)


#------------------------------------------------ Ejecución de programa -------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Las cadenas en consultas de sql se representan unicamente con `'mitexto'`. Es decir, la cadena debe estar entre comillas simples. Tu la pones entre comillas dobles, eso puede ser la causa de tu error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo primero que te recomendaría es que no crees la base de datos con palabras separadas ni con tildes eso es una mala practica aparte ni siquiera creaste una base de datos.

hazlo así y ponle la extensión al final

`miConexion = sqlite3.connect("RegistroDeFarmacos.db")`

Segundo tu función borrarcambios no esta funcionando por que para limpiar los campos hay que utilizar el método delete con los entrys no con las variables,
ejemplo de como debe hacerse:

```
    def borrarCampos():
       cuadroID.delete(0,END)
       cuadroNombre.delete(0,END)
       cuadroClas.delete(0,END)
       cuadroHum.delete(0,END)
       cuadriAnim.delete(0,END)
       cuadroFun.delete(1.0, END) #para indicar qué caracteres borrar
       cuadroFF.delete(0,END)
       cuadroFE.delete(0,END)
       cuadroProp.delete(1.0, END)
```

y para la función de crear hazlo de esta forma a mi parecer es mas legible y entendible, y que no se te olvide cerrar la conexión a la base de datos, probé tu código con estos cambios que efectué y funciona bien.

creas una variable y le pasas una tupla `registro = (valores, que, almacenaras, en, la, db)`

luego le pasas la tupla a la consulta y los valores que almacenaste en la tupla reemplazaran a cada uno de estos signo ?,?,?...

```
    def crear():
       try:
           miConexion = sqlite3.connect("RegistrodeFármacos.db")

           miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

           registro = (cuadroID.get(), cuadroNombre.get(), cuadroClas.get(), 
                       cuadroHum.get(), cuadroAnim.get(), cuadroFun.get(1.0,END), 
                       cuadroFF.get(), cuadroFE.get(), cuadroProp.get(1.0, END))

           print(registro)

           miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATOS_FARMACOS VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
                            registro)

           miConexion.commit()


           messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro realizado exitosamente")

           miconexion.close()
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)
```

la variable myid tiene que ser tipo int `miID = IntVar()` tu la tenias de tipo string